# Implementing Silent AAD Authentication in Bots

Tags: authentication, botframework

Can we implement something like below in bot framework.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/master/msteams-platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-AAD.md

Currently the user has to launch a window to authenticate. But if above works then if user is alreeady connected to some Azure AD then it can pick up auth tokent automatically. Please let me know.

Comment: Are you making a feature request or asking if this is already currently possible?

Comment: I understand this functionality is channel-specific and is already available in MS Teams using the Bot Framework. Are you trying to achieve this functionality in MS Teams or a different channel? In what context does the user have to launch a window to authenticate?

Comment: If it’s not available then yes a features request. I was hoping to have something similar for other channels like webchat, Facebook etc.

Answer (score 0):

Silent auth is channel-specific functionality and is currently available in Teams, Web Chat, and the Bot Emulator. As for Facebook Messenger, there are a lot of things you can do with their [webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook/) so it's hard to say if this is possible or not.